# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory When using rest easy with JAVA 8 on WildFly8.2.0

Tags: wildfly, resteasy, seam, wildfly-8

I am using rest easy for getting and posting the data from a third party URL, When I am calling the get service using the below code I am getting the ClassNotFoundException "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"

```
final ClientRequest request = createRequest(url,acceptType,consumesType,body);
final byte[] encodedCredentials = (userName + ":" + password)
            .getBytes();
    final String encodedAuto = Base64.encodeBytes(encodedCredentials);
    request.header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuto);
try {
        request.addAuthenticationHeaders(request, userName,
                password);
        response = request.get(String.class);
        if (response != null) {
            logger.info("Status of the REST Call:"
                    + response.getStatus());
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Failed the get the data from PM", e);
    }
```

And the createRequest method is as below

```
public ClientRequest createRequest(final String urlString,
        final String acceptType, final String consumesType,
        final String body) {
    final ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(urlString);
    request.accept(acceptType);
    if (body != null) {
        request.body(consumesType, body);
    }
    request.header("Content-Type", consumesType);
    // request.header("Accept", acceptType);

    return request;
}
```

When it is executing response = request.get(request); it is throwing SSLSocketFactory ClassNotFoundException, as per my analysis this class is available on rt.jar which is not required to add to the WildFly server or deployments lib folder.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.execute(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:81) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.execute(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:107) [resteasy-crypto-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:473) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:704) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:509) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:537) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
at com.example.main.framework.service.RestClientService.get(RestClientService.java:46) [main-ejb.jar:]
at com.example.main.entity.validator.EntityValidator.getPMAccountDetails(EntityValidator.java:2866) [main-ejb.jar:]
at com.example.main.entity.validator.EntityValidator.validateCompanySettingPortfolioMgr(EntityValidator.java:2633) [main-ejb.jar:]
at com.example.main.action.codegen.CompanySettingPortfolioMgrHome.persist(CompanySettingPortfolioMgrHome.java:329) [main-ejb.jar:]
... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory from [Module "org.apache.commons.httpclient:main" from local module loader @6043cd28 (finder: local module finder @cb51256 (roots: D:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules,D:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
... 120 more
```

If we add rt.jar to the wildfly module then it throws ClassNotFoundException related to classes in jsse.jar which is as part of JDK 1.8 lib. Then I realized that we should not add these jars to neither httpclient module nor deployment lib folder.

Please let me know if any one has solution for this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue got resolved after adding the "javax.api" dependency to the module.xml for the module org.apache.commons.httpclient.

```
<module ...>

    <resources>
        ...
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        ....
        <module name="javax.api"/> 
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with an issue regarding PostgreSQL 10 in Wildfly 10.1.0. Instead of adding the dependency to httpclient, I did so for the postgres module.